# Ordenar array asociativo en jquery

Tags: jquery, array, object, ordenamiento

Tengo esta estructura devuelta de una función anterior en PHP, que ha devuelto un array asociativo via ajax, que he parseado a JSON con Jquery, y que no puedo ordenar antes porque necesita ser previsualizado primero, en el orden en el que viene (por clave ascendente como se puede ver):

```
0: "INTEGECRE-1#_#1.80"
1: "INTEGECRE-3#_#2.40"
2: "INTEGECRE-5#_#2.20"
3: "INTEGECRE-16#_#3.70"
4: "INTEGECRE-170#_#2.10"
5: "INTEGECRE-1408#_#3.80"
```

Después de aplicar la siguiente función, que separa las claves de las duraciones separadas por "#_#", estoy intentando meterlo todo en un array clave-valor, en el que la clave es el nombre identificativo INTEGECRE-* emparejado con su duracion "1.80", que además, estoy intentando ordenar por duración, de forma ascendente.

```
    function montarEscenariosByAlgoritmo(externalIdsCresta, algoritmo){
        var extIds = [];
        var extIdsOrdenados = [];
        $.each(externalIdsCresta, function(id, cpCresta){
            var cpCrestaObj = cpCresta.split("#_#");
            if(cpCrestaObj[0] != null && cpCrestaObj[0] != undefined && $.trim(cpCrestaObj[0]) != ""){
                var cpCrestaId = cpCrestaObj[0];
            }
            if(cpCrestaObj[1] != null && cpCrestaObj[1] != undefined && $.trim(cpCrestaObj[1]) != ""){
                var duracion = cpCrestaObj[1];
            }
            extIds[cpCrestaId] = duracion;
        });

        extIdsOrdenados = extIds.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.cpCrestaId) - parseFloat(b.cpCrestaId);
        });
}
```

me queda esta estructura después de aplicar la función anterior, pero no está ordenado...

```
INTEGECRE-1: "1.80"
INTEGECRE-3: "2.40"
INTEGECRE-5: "2.20"
INTEGECRE-16: "3.70"
INTEGECRE-170: "2.10"
INTEGECRE-1408: "3.80"
```

Intento ordenarlo de esta forma pero no lo hace:

```
extIdsOrdenados = extIds.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.cpCrestaId) - parseFloat(b.cpCrestaId);
});
```

Necesito ordenarla para que me quede ordenado por valor, no por clave:

```
INTEGECRE-1: "1.80"
INTEGECRE-170: "2.10"
INTEGECRE-5: "2.20"
INTEGECRE-3: "2.40"
INTEGECRE-16: "3.70"
INTEGECRE-1408: "3.80"
```

Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Hola Nando. Para que podamos ayudarte, has de mostrar tu intento de ordenacion y explicar tu problema concreto . Intenta ademas crear un codigo completo ([mcve]) para que se pueda meter en un snippet y poder ejecutarse directamente y asi ver y probar mejor tu código. Un saludo

Comment: Hola lois6b , lo he ampliado. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Gracias por añadir el codigo de ordenacion. Puedes añadir un ejemplo completo  donde tenga la estructura de datos original y asi ver como cada funcion la va convirtiendo?  Asi veremos como se comporta tu intento de ordenacion

Comment: ¿Qué es en sí la *estructura* que muestras, es un array, un JSON, una cadena...?¿Dónde se genera esa estructura? ¿Por qué no la ordenas a otro nivel (donde se produce por ejemplo)? Yo veo que das demasiadas vueltas para hacer algo que podría ser más simple, lo digo por el código que veo (un bucle, varios `if`, un `trim`, etc, etc) y porque en la pregunta leo: *Tengo esta estructura devuelta de una función anterior*, o sea, como si ya has manoseado los datos anteriormente y de nuevo vuelves a manosearlos, ¿por qué tanta manipulación de unos mismos datos?

Comment: A. Cedano te acabo de responder, Gracias

Comment: lois6b he explicado un poco mejor el problema, a ver si así se entiende un poco mejor. Gracias

Comment: `extIds.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.cpCrestaId.localeCompare(b.cpCrestaId);
});` ¿De esta forma te lo ordenada?

Comment: Francisco Garrido, gracias por la respuesta, pero parece que no funciona ese arreglo, no modifica el orden y creo que es porque las claves no son fijas, pero agradezco tu ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás mezclando dos conceptos: mapas y listas.

```js
let entrada = {
  0: "INTEGECRE-1#_#1.80",
  1: "INTEGECRE-3#_#2.40",
  2: "INTEGECRE-5#_#2.20",
  3: "INTEGECRE-16#_#3.70",
  4: "INTEGECRE-170#_#2.10",
  5: "INTEGECRE-1408#_#3.80"
}
      
function montarEscenariosByAlgoritmo(externalIdsCresta, algoritmo){
  var extIds = [];
  var extIdsOrdenados = [];
  $.each(externalIdsCresta, function(id, cpCresta){
    
    var cpCrestaObj = cpCresta.split("#_#");
    if(cpCrestaObj[0] != null && cpCrestaObj[0] != undefined && $.trim(cpCrestaObj[0]) != ""){
        var cpCrestaId = cpCrestaObj[0];
    }
    if(cpCrestaObj[1] != null && cpCrestaObj[1] != undefined && $.trim(cpCrestaObj[1]) != ""){
        var duracion = cpCrestaObj[1];
    }
    console.log('Tenemos id:',cpCrestaId,' y duracion', duracion);
    extIds[cpCrestaId] = duracion;
  });
  console.log('Procesados', extIds.length,'elementos');
  extIdsOrdenados = extIds.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.cpCrestaId) - parseFloat(b.cpCrestaId);
  });
  return extIds;
}

let salida = montarEscenariosByAlgoritmo(entrada);

console.log('Como array', salida);
console.log('Lista de valores (como objeto):',Object.entries(salida));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El problema es que quieres devolver una lista, pero los índices han de ser numéricos, con lo que estás creando un nuevo mapa sobre un objeto array.
Al final, tienes un array con cero elementos pero con varios atributos extras que la clase Array no contempla y no sabe manejar (no sabe que están ahí).

La solución más sencilla es tener un array de entradas (duplas) y ordenarlo, ya que un mapa no es ordenable:

```js
let entrada = {
 0: 'INTEGECRE-1#_#1.80',
 1: 'INTEGECRE-3#_#2.40',
 2: 'INTEGECRE-5#_#2.20',
 3: 'INTEGECRE-16#_#3.70',
 4: 'INTEGECRE-170#_#2.10',
 5: 'INTEGECRE-1408#_#3.80'
}

function montarEscenariosByAlgoritmo(externalIdsCresta, algoritmo) {
 var extIds = [];
 var extIdsOrdenados = [];
 $.each(externalIdsCresta, function (id, cpCresta) {
  const cpCrestaObj = cpCresta.split('#_#');
  let cpCrestaId, duracion;
  if (cpCrestaObj[0] && $.trim(cpCrestaObj[0])) {
   cpCrestaId = cpCrestaObj[0];
  }
  if (cpCrestaObj[1] && $.trim(cpCrestaObj[1])) {
   duracion = +cpCrestaObj[1];
  }
  
  extIds.push({ cpCrestaId, duracion });
 });
 
 extIdsOrdenados = extIds.sort(function (a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.duracion) - parseFloat(b.duracion);
 });
 return extIdsOrdenados;
}

let salida = montarEscenariosByAlgoritmo(entrada);

console.log(salida);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo Lozano, devuelve los datos como los necesito. Gracias por la explicación